# Django admin lag dates in model based on view

Tags: python, django

In Django I builded a model based on view and in admin account i see there is added values that are not present in postgresql database.
These are ordered values in db view:
[image]

but in admin values looks like laged by 1 day:
[image]

Model in django looks like this:

```
class VBalance(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)

class Meta:
    managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
    db_table = 'v_balance'

def __str__(self) -> str:
    # return "Balance: " + "{:.2f}".format(self.balance) + " on: " + self.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    return "Balance: " + str(self.balance) + " on: " + self.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT - db screeens with data:

View v_balance is builded like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW rap.v_balance
AS SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id,
    balance_avg.date,
    avg(balance_avg.balance) AS balance
   FROM ( SELECT balance.date + 1 AS date,
            sum(balance.amount) OVER (ORDER BY balance.date) AS balance
           FROM ( SELECT COALESCE(b.date, dt.dt::date) AS date,
                    b.amount
                   FROM generate_series('2021-08-24 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone, CURRENT_DATE::timestamp with time zone, '1 day'::interval) dt(dt)
                     LEFT JOIN import.balance b ON date(dt.dt) = b.date
                UNION
                 SELECT transactions.date,
                    transactions.amount
                   FROM ( SELECT date(transactions_xtb.close_time) AS date,
                            sum(transactions_xtb.net_profit) AS amount
                           FROM import.transactions_xtb
                          GROUP BY (date(transactions_xtb.close_time))
                          ORDER BY (date(transactions_xtb.close_time))) transactions
          ORDER BY 1) balance
          ORDER BY (balance.date + 1)) balance_avg
  GROUP BY balance_avg.date;
```

It's based on two tables: balance and transactions.
Table balance have only one row and it's not null:
[image]

Table transactions also dont have null values:
[image]

What's more it's look like django lag date becuase in my view recent date is: **2022-01-02** but in Django is: **2022-01-01**.
So dates are laged but values are not.

Comment: Show your ModelAdmin for that app/model?

Comment: from django.contrib import admin

from .models import VMarketInfo, VTransactions, VBalance
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(VMarketInfo)
admin.site.register(VTransactions)
admin.site.register(VBalance)

U mean this?

Comment: I think the problem is in your table. You seem to have gotten a null in the table. Double check and remove the null

Comment: All the dates look good except for the last one which is 24th. and the value for that is None so I think you should check your dataset and mainly your database